# Validación personalizada dependiente en Angular

Tags: angular, validación

Estoy comenzando con Angular y el paradigma orientado a objetos.

Estoy intentando realizar una validación en un Reactive Form, en donde me valide la longitud del CVV de una tarjeta de crédito (4 dígitos si es Amex, 3 para el resto). Armé la siguiente función pero no se como devolver la función AbstractControl.

intenté también hacer la comprobación dentro del validador, pero me indica que el lenght no es compatible con AbstractControl.

Desde ya muchas gracias a quien me pueda guiar un poco, estoy perdido en cuanto a validaciones compuestas de este tipo.

Saludos.

**.ts**

```
formTarjeta: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.formTarjeta=this.formBuilder.group({
      Empresa: ['', [Validators.required]],
       cvv: ['',[this.validarCvv]],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

EmpresaCvv(){
  const cvv4 = "American Express";
  const Empresa = this.formTarjeta.get('Empresa')!.value;
  if (Empresa == cvv4) {return true;}
  else {return false;}
}

LongitudCvv(){
  const cvv = this.formTarjeta.get('cvv')!.value
  if (cvv.lenght == 3) {return "3";}
  if (cvv.lenght == 4) {return "4";}
  else {return null;}
}

validarCvv: ValidatorFn = (
  control: AbstractControl
  ): ValidationErrors | null =>{
    const cvv = control.get("cvv");
  if (this.EmpresaCvv() == true && this.LongitudCvv() == "4") {return null;}
  if (this.EmpresaCvv() == false && this.LongitudCvv() == "3") {return null;} 
  else {return ;} ;
```

**Actualización **

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formTarjeta" (ngSubmit)="guardarTarjeta()">
//...
<select name="Empresa" class="form-control" formControlName="Empresa" >
            <option value="" disabled>Empresa emisora</option>
            <option value= "American Express">American Express</option>
            <option value= "Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
        </select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="cvv" placeholder="CVV">
//...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso como la validación depende de dos controles, te recomiendo que en vez de crear un validador para el campo `cvv`, lo crees para el `FormGroup` que contiene ambos campos.

Para asignar el validador al `FormGroup`, lo puedes hacer a pasando un objeto de configuración como segundo argumento de `formBuilder.group()`

```
this.formTarjeta = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    Empresa: ['', [Validators.required]],
    cvv: [''],
  },
  { validators: [this.validarCvv] } // <----
);
```

Y una vez hecho esto, como validador puedes usar algo similar al siguiente código:

```
validarCvv: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const { Empresa, cvv } = control.value; // Extraemos valores de ambos campos necesarios

  // comprobamos que los controles Empresa y cvv existan en el FormGroup
  // antes de ejecutar la validación.
  if (Empresa === undefined || cvv === undefined) {
    throw Error(
      '(validarCvv): Alguno de los controles "Empresa" y/o "cvv" no se encontraron en el FormGroup aplicado.'
    );
  }

  // Calculamos longitud de cvv, convirtiendo a String por si fuera number.
  const cvvLength = cvv ? String(cvv).length : 0;

  if (
    (Empresa === 'American Express' && cvvLength === 4) || // AMEX => 4
    (Empresa && Empresa !== 'American Express' && cvvLength === 3) // OTROS => 3
  ) {
    return null; // Validación correcta, devolvemos null
  }

  return { incorrectCvv: true }; // validación incorrecta, devolvemos un error personalizado.
};
```

Como ves si la validación es correcta, el validador debe devolver `null` y si hay algún error un objeto con los errores. En este caso he usado `{ incorrectCvv: true }` pero lo puedes personalizar de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Como el validador esta aplicado al `FormGroup`, para comprobar el estado de validación del mismo tendrás que hacerlo a través del grupo, por ejemplo usando `formTarjeta.hasError('incorrectCvv')`

un saludo

Comment: antes que nada te agradezco por haberte tomado el tiempo de responderme y detallar la función que utilizaste, desde ya me fue de gran ayuda para entender las validaciones compuestas que se encuentran poco documentadas en el IO de Angular..   Te comento que pruebo la función pero me sigue pasando lo mismo que en anteriores que he probado.. me devuelve un **haserrors false**, por algún motivo no logro que me devuelva el true cuando corresponde (estimo que tiene que ver con que AbstractControl no es compatible con el Length)..

Comment: @DanielFabbri Que raro... Puedes por favor añadir en la pregunta original el código html del template donde enlazas el formulario para echarle un vistazo? De todas formas he probado el código en stackblitz y funciona correctamente, puedes verlo [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x5hyhz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).  He corregido eso sí, la línea de `cvvLength` ya que no había contemplado el caso que `cvv` fuera `null`.

Comment: ahi lo copié más abajo, muchas gracias!

Comment: @DanielFabbri Parece estar todo correcto en el código que has puesto del template. Lo que me parece extraño, que *hasError* te devuelva `null`. Puedes añadir también la parte donde estés usando esa función.  // Y otra cosa, el codigo nuevo lo has pegado dentro de una respuesta, si puedes por favor muevelo dentro de la pregunta original y borra la respuesta, para que asi quede todo el codigo relacionado junto y sea mas facil de visualizar para futuros usuarios que pudieran acceder a esta pregunta. slds

Comment: [enlace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5tmnsl?file=src/app/app.component.html) dejo en StackBlitz el código completo.. con gusto subiría un screen donde demuestra que el cvv queda válido con tan solo 1 dígito (debido al Validators.Required)..  ahora corrijo lo indicado sobre la publicación.

Comment: @DanielFabbri Revisando el codigo del stackblitz, el unico error asi que he visto es que a la hora de configurar el form tienes `{ Validators: [this.validarCvv] }` con `V` mayuscula y debe ser en minúscula -> `{ validators: [this.validarCvv] }` // Respecto a lo del campo `cvv`, como el validador esta en el grupo del formulario el campo `cvv` en si será valido en cuanto introduzcas cualquier cosa. Para comprobar ambas condiciones puedes escribir una condicion compuesta del tipo `"form.get('cvv')!.valid && !form.hasError('incorrectCvv')"`.

Comment: Listo! era la v en minúscula en el .ts,!! Te agradezco muchísimo por el tiempo en explicarme todo detalladamente y en revisar los errores.. pude entenderlo mucho mejor!!

Comment: Nada... un placer. Me alegro que por fin hayamos conseguido que funcione todo. un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Es extraño, en Stackblitz funciona..

En el template además de otros campos (Titular, numero, vencimiento), tengo los mismos parámetros.. copio el template sin los *div class* de Bootstrap..

El resto está todo igual, pero visualizandolo en el *localhost* me genera siempre un *null*, no devuelve nunca un *true*, incluso si existe un sólo dígito en el campo..

```
<form [formGroup]="formTarjeta" (ngSubmit)="guardarTarjeta()">
//...
<select name="Empresa" class="form-control" formControlName="Empresa" >
            <option value="" disabled>Empresa emisora</option>
            <option value= "American Express">American Express</option>
            <option value= "Visa">Visa</option>
            <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
        </select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="cvv" placeholder="CVV">
//...
</form>
```